# How to print the version of a maven library dependency to console

Tags: java

Can someone help me on how to print the version of a library to the console? For example, my dependency in pom.xml is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>AbcClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>xyz</classifier>
</dependency>
```

And the exact library that is downloaded is "AbcClient-1.0-20171107.000833-111.jar". I want the full name of the library with its version to be printed to the console.

Example console output:
AbcClient-1.0-20171107.000833-111.jar

Comment: *When* do you want it printed to console? During Maven build? At runtime?

Comment: improved readability of question, may need further edits to clarify if needed at run time or build time.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the dependency jar and its version then did you try Apache Maven Dependency Plugin?

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

Sample Usage on one of my project

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson-jaxrs-json-provider
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.8:provided
[INFO] | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.8:compile
```